# Reading PDF with format info like Bold, text size

Tags: pdf, text, formatting

I need to read a PDF file for its text while also getting the formatting. Like I don't need it to be exactly the same format, I just need to know if some text is bold or not (font weight) and the size of the text.

I can read docx files while also getting the formatting information, so if there is a way to convert the PDF to doc/docx file that also works.

Any language will do as long as the resources needed can run on a Linux server.

### What I have tried

- pypdf / PyPDF2 ( Cant get the formatting)
- [PDFminer](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/) ( cant get the formatting )
- Xpdf by FooLabs ( again no option to get any formatting)
- Using shell script to automate the process of opening a PDF in Microsoft Word and saving it as docx file( it works... but not feasible for Linux server)

Comment: This is going to be really tough. Good PDF producers will use a bold variant of a font to represent bold text but there are way too many PDF files out there that use a normal font and repeat the word with the origin offset by a pixel a couple of times to mimic a bold font. You won't be able to tell the difference. My suggestion... which you won't like... would be to render the PDF to a bitmap and feed that image to an OCR API that will give you the style information.

Comment: You say you *"need to read a pdf file for its text while also getting the formatting"*; is it really about a single PDF? Or about a collection of PDFs from the same producing software? In that case there might be a way. On the other hand, if you want to implement the task for generic documents tossed your way, even getting it right 80% of the time is likely to be a major project, way beyond the format of a stack overflow answer.